# ruby selenium click on button with class name

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm using ruby and selenium to test a web page, with the two buttons below

```
<div class="AVdis">
  <span class="gwt-InlineHTML"/>
    <a class="AVcur" name="attendEdit"; font-size: 12px;">[edit]</a>
</div>
<div class="lineHeight">
  <button type="button" class="pcbtn" style="display: inline-block;">yes</button>
</div>
```

I've tried to use

```
driver.find_elements(:class, 'AVcur').click 
driver.find_elements(:class, 'pcbtn').click
```

but it doesn't work, please advise.

Thanks

updated the full HTML code(the part code of class 'pcbtn' ONLY, it doesn't include the part with class 'AVcur'.):

```
<body>
  <iframe src="javascript:'';" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px; display: block;"/>
  <iframe src="javascript:''" id="Attend" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;"/>
  <div style="display: none;"/>
    <div class="GFKFO5SBPF hBody nClientFalse">
      <div class="left" style="width: 198px;">
        <div class="contents nClientFalse2">
          <div class="AVright">
            <div class="GFKFO5SBIQ">
              <div class="AVfirstTd">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <div>
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pcattd_record" width="630px">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr class="GFKFO5SBCS">
                                <tr class="GFKFO5SBCS">
                                  <th>
                                    <td>
                                      <table class="noborder">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <td>
                                              <div class="lineHeight">
                                                <button type="button" class="pcbtn" style="display: inline-block;">press button</button>
```

Comment: `find_elements` may return multiple elements with the specified class. Try `find_elements(:class, 'AVcur')[0].click`

Comment: @Santosh: got error `<main>': undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: I think your syntax might be wrong. Try `find_elements(:class => 'AVcur')[0].click`

Comment: Are you sure the page has an element with class 'AVcur'?

Comment: @Santosh: yes I pasted the html code, <a class="AVcur" name="attendEdit"; font-size: 12px;">[edit]</a>

Comment: This html synax is wrong. Make this change `<a class="AVcur" name="attendEdit" style="font-size: 12px;">[edit]</a>`

Comment: driver.find_element(:css, '.pcbtn').click and driver.find_element(:css, 'a.AVcur').click

Comment: @bcar thanks, but got error: Could not find element: {"using":"css selector","value":".pcbtn"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError) and Could not find element: {"using":"css selector","value":"a.AVcur"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: @Santosh, I updated the full HTML code, please advise, thanks

Comment: @xxd, The HTML doesnt have an element with class 'AVcur'

Comment: @Santosh, sorry this the part code of class 'pcbtn', it didn't include the part with class 'AVcur'.

Comment: Too complex html structure

Comment: BTW, perhaps irrelevant to this question, but your `div` tag on line 4 is self-closing. Your indentation suggests you intend to just have an open tag `  <div style="display: none;">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to click it, using xpath:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='AVdis']//a[@name='attendEdit']").click
```

Second element xpath:

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='lineHeight']//button[@class='pcbtn'][text()='yes']").click
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still get error, `raw_execute': Could not find element: {"using":"xpath","value":"//div[@class='AVdis']//a[@name='attendEdit']"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError), why I can't find those elements?

Comment: I see that button[@class='pcbtn'] is within the iframe, you need to switch to that iframe first, before clicking on it (you might google for switchin between iframes in ruby webdriver). Maybe the first element is also within iframe? The thing is webdriver can't find elements that are within iframe, if you not switch "into" it

Comment: I think the two iframes <iframe src="javascript:....."/> are closed at the beginning?

Comment: oh, yes, correct. Then it's wierd. If you use firefox and firebug, there is FirePath tab in it, does it find xpath //div[@class='AVdis']//a[@name='attendEdit'] ? If it's not within iframe, maybe it's within invisible-under-ajax area of the page, where you should scroll/move-mouse first?

Answer (score 0):

Click an element:

```
driver.find_element(css: 'a').click
```